# Adding the values of outliers from a list to several plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

How I can add the value of outliers (add `outliers_values.)` to the each box plot. I tried to use the `geom_text` but it did not work!

```
outlier_values.<-lapply(mtcars[-c(8,9)], function(x){outlier_values <- boxplot.stats(x)$out})

mtcars_m = melt(mtcars[,-c(8,9)])
names(mtcars_m)=c("Models","CI")
box.plot<- ggplot(mtcars_m, aes(Models, CI,fill=Models)) + geom_boxplot(width = 0.1)+ facet_wrap(~ Models,scales = "free")+
           guides(fill=FALSE)+labs(x="",y="")

install.packages("reshape2")
library(reshape2)
install.packages("plyr")
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
```

Comment: your `melt` step does not work, is `CI` your value or your variable?

Comment: @ Al14, please install the packages above.

Comment: Yes I still get this error `Using ID as id variables`

Comment: @Al14 `reshape2::melt(mtcars[,-c(8,9)])` works fine for me. "No id variables; using all as measure variables" is a friendly message, not an error.

Comment: @no, that one is not error, just run the mtcars_m and you can see the data set